# Adding a path to the system using environ module

Tags: python, environ

In a setting file I append a path to the system hardcoding the url like this:

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/path/to/projectdir')
```

It works.

As soon as I want to make it relative, it fails even if I retrieve the exact path with environ module.

```
import environ

ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 3
sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR.path())
```

To me the incredible thing is that `print(ROOT_DIR.path())` outputs the exact url of project_dir.

```
print(ROOT_DIR.path())
> '/home/user/path/to/projectdir'
```

Here is the tree of my project.

```
project_dir
└── soloscrap
    └── soloscrap
        ├── settings.py
```

How could I add this path then? Isn't it weird?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but why not a) run python setup.py develop (which will create your virtual links and add it to your path) and b) if you can't find your path as you want, does it have __init__.py in it?

Comment: How about something like: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`. This, or some variation, is what I usually use to get the path to the directory of a file/a project directory.

Comment: @elethan it was to avoid this imbricated os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))) But this one works returning the same path

Comment: @Kelvin Thanks for your help. Of course there is an init file. But the problem came from that paths are already in sys when I import environ. So it's too late to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `environ` arrives too late and the paths are already fixed. So the solution seems to be something like this:

```
SYSPATH = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(
        os.path.dirname(
            os.path.abspath(__file__)
        )
    )
)

sys.path.append(SYSPATH)
```

Which is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get relative paths how about:

```
os.path.join("..", "..", __file__)
```

(Slightly different due to terminal)

```
In [1]: import os

In [3]: os.getcwd()
Out[3]: 'c:\\Temp\\foo\\bar'

In [4]: os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..','..',__name__))
Out[4]: 'c:\\Temp\\__main__'

In [5]:
```

Comment: with the use of '..' I don't get the same result as I have with os.path.dirname() Anyway, I stick to dirname()